# An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, hresult

suddenly when i run my web application i get this error :

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Users\rafael\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\284bddf3\431c8965\App_Web_homepage.aspx.cdcab7d2.vmizb1js.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The handle is invalid. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))

Here's the stack trace:

```
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\rafael\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\284bddf3\431c8965\App_Web_homepage.aspx.cdcab7d2.vmizb1js.dll' or one of its dependencies. The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +39
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +132
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity) +28
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults.get_CompiledAssembly() +93
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.CreateBuildResult(CompilerResults results) +60
   System.Web.Compilation.TemplateControlBuildProvider.CreateBuildResult(CompilerResults results) +36
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetBuildResult(CompilerResults results) +16
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +9086138
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +320
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +111
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +125
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +52
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +31
   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +40
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +167
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +517

[HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for /homepage.aspx.]
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +816
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path, Boolean preserveForm) +57
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path) +32
   photography.Global.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in F:\Web Prog\my work\mcpd\gallery\photography\photography\Global.asax.cs:27
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

I have no idea what's it all about. So i'd be grateful if i got any help.

Comment: you got this one time, or just not run any more ?

Comment: @Aristos it doesn't run anymore.

Comment: What is your web.config - maybe you place it there a temporary directory that you do not have the correct permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the option to `stop and restart the website`?

This should, in theory, `recycle the application pool for your site`, which might be enough to correct the problem.

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Do you mean restarting it while it's running ? i tried that and didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @RafaelAdel Clear out the temporary ASP.Net files on the server, when you deploy, and that should sort you out.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following on your Server:

1. Open the command prompt and run the following command:
2. C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET.NET Framework\Framework Version\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Where .NET framework version can be replaced with the .NET framework of your application project. either v2.0.50727 or 4.0 e.t.c

Try running the application again and you'll be fine.